# Memory error in Word2vec while loading freebase-skipgram model

Tags: python-2.7, freebase, word2vec

I am trying to use word2vec and using freebase skip gram model. But I'm unable to load the model due to memory error.

Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('freebase-vectors-skipgram1000.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-a1cfacf48c94> in <module>()
      1 model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
----> 2 model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('freebase-vectors-skipgram1000.bin.gz', binary=True)

/../../word2vec.pyc in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, norm_only)
    583             vocab_size, layer1_size = map(int, header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
    584             result = Word2Vec(size=layer1_size)
--> 585             result.syn0 = zeros((vocab_size, layer1_size), dtype=REAL)
    586             if binary:
    587                 binary_len = dtype(REAL).itemsize * layer1_size

MemoryError:
```

But the same thing is working fine with google news using following code:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

I am unable to understand why. Is it that freebase requires much more memory than google news? I feel that shouldn't be the case. Am i missing something here?

Comment: model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True) how long does this line take to be run? on my 4gb ram laptop it does not seem to finish.

Comment: I haven't tested it on a 4GB machine but I believe it won't work on 4 GB machine as GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz is > 1.5GB and when uncompressed it will be much more and would require that much RAM memory and you OS might eat up around a GB of RAM. But you should at least get memory error in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out and this was due to memory requirement of freebase. When ran on 8gb machine with other ipython notebook running this was giving me the error. closing all other process and other notebooks allowed me to load it finally!